# sort test templated function lambda: illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: c++, lambda

There's tons of people asking this question on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find one with the same problem I am experiencing.

I've written some sorting routines, and I am trying to write re-usable functions for testing these routines, however, the more sorts I write the more complicated my functions are getting, almost to the point where I'd rather just copy paste the code for each sort.

The following are the signatures for the sort functions I am testing:

```
template<typename FwdIterator, typename Comparator = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIterator>::value_type>>
void sort_selection(FwdIterator beg, FwdIterator end, Comparator cmp = Comparator())

template<typename BidirIt, typename Comparator = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type>>
void sort_insertion(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator())

template<typename BidirIt, typename Comparator = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type>>
void sort_merge(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator())

template<typename BidirIt, typename Comparator = std::less_equal<typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type>>
void sort_quick(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, Comparator cmp = Comparator())
```

The main difference being the default comparator for `sort_quick`.

The following are the templated functions I am trying to get to work for testing the sorts:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <dapps/containers/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::allocator;
using std::less;
using std::less_equal;
using boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer;

template<typename Func, typename Comp>
static void sort_test_uniques(const string & name, Func sort, Comp comparator)
{
    vector<int> orig{ 1, 4, 5, 3, 2 }, soln{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    cout << "Testing " << name << ".\n" << "Execution time:";
    {
        auto_cpu_timer t;
        sort<vector<int>, Comp>(orig.begin(), orig.end(), comparator);
    }
    assert(orig == soln);
    cout << "Result: PASS\n" << endl;
}

template<typename Func, typename Comp>
static void sort_test_duplicates(const string & name, Func sort, Comp comparator)
{
    vector<int> orig{ 1, 4, 5, 3, 1 }, soln{ 1, 1, 3, 4, 5 };
    cout << "Testing " << name << " with duplicates.\n" << "Execution time:";
    {
        auto_cpu_timer t;
        sort<vector<int>, Comp>(orig.begin(), orig.end(), comparator);
    }
    assert(orig == soln);
    cout << "Result: PASS\n" << endl;
}

template<typename Func, typename Comp>
static void sort_test(const string & name, Func sort, Comp comparator)
{
    sort_test_uniques(name, sort, comparator);
    sort_test_duplicates(name, sort, comparator);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv [])
{
    using iterator = vector<int>::iterator;

    sort_test("sort_selection", &sort_selection<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_insertion", &sort_insertion<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_merge", &sort_merge<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_quick", &sort_quick<iterator>, less_equal<int>());
    sort_test("std:sort", &std::sort<iterator>, less<int>());

    return 0;
}
```

I added the second template parameter, `Comp` to the functions since sort_quick requires a different comparator when dealing with duplicates.

The compiler is giving me: `error C2275: 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' : illegal use of this type as an expression`
Since I am taking the function (Func parameter) by lambda or function pointer (not sure about this), the functions do not know about the default values for the comparator, so i figured I needed to be explicit and pass the comparators.

If I don't explicitly pass the template parameters and  instead call `sort(orig.begin(), orig.end(), comparator);` the compiler gives me: `error C2197: 'void (__cdecl *)(iterator,iterator)' : too many arguments for call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating template functions in your `main()` function when you call `sort_test`. Since the template instantiation is occurring here, all the knowledge about the template types need to be provided before passing the function pointer to the `sort_test()` method. This also means that you should not provide the template parameters when you call your `sort()` argument function, since it is already a fully instantiated function pointer.

You are doing that for the first four (your custom sort methods), but `std::sort` actually has overloaded methods:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );

template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

(from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort))

The compiler is choosing the first method to instantiate since you only provide the definition of the function with one template parameter (`<iterator>`). You must provide both template parameters to `std::sort(...)` when defining the function you are passing to `sort_test`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv [])
{
    using iterator = vector<int>::iterator;

    sort_test("sort_selection", &sort_selection<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_insertion", &sort_insertion<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_merge", &sort_merge<iterator>, less<int>());
    sort_test("sort_quick", &sort_quick<iterator>, less_equal<int>());
    sort_test("std:sort", &std::sort<iterator, less<int>>, less<int>());

    return 0;
}
```